# Posting multiple values with Curl to Sinatra

Tags: ruby, rest, post, curl, sinatra

This is a simple enough one but I've tried everything that makes sense to me.

Basically I have a Sinatra app and with a curl post, am trying to pass in multiple values.
This is the curl post that needs to be accepted:

```
curl -I -X POST http://127.0.0.1:4567/simplepost/123?value=abc
```

And Heres what I have on the sinatra side

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra/base'


class Go< Sinatra::Base
    #post '/simplepost/:param1:param2' do
    #post '/simplepost/:param1 ?value= :param2' do
    post '/simplepost/:param1?value=:param2' do
    #post '/simplepost/:param1?:param2' do



    puts params[:param1]
    puts params[:param2]

  end
end


Go.run!
```

Sadly, each one of these returns a different type of result. Some are 404's, some are 
12,3
where 12 is param1 and 3 is param2.

Can anyone help me figure out what kind of route I need to add to sinatra to break that curl post into 2 params?

Comment: Write your own Rack app that uses some regex if it's nothing more.

Comment: In the end, I used a splat.  IE  post 'simplepost/:param1*'
The wildcard/star means take in any params defined by the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me help you with Sinatra, my friend :)

```
ruby -r sinatra -e "post('/postMan/:someParam'){puts params[:someParam]; puts params[:otherParam]}"
```

and on the curl side:

```
curl -I -X POST http://127.0.0.1:4567/postMan/123456?otherParam=12
```